# New products not showing until manually reindexing although cron is running

Tags: magento2, product, indexing, reindex, index

I am running Magento 2.1.2 and when creating new products they don't show up on the website until I manually run bin/magento indexer:reindex and flush the cache.

This sounds like a cron problem as all the indexs are set to update on schedule but other parts of the index are being refreshed without problems such as when creating a new attribute set it warns about the indexers being invalid and is fixed within a minute.

I don't believe this has always been a problem and may have been caused from recently restoring to a backup (rebuilt the Rackspace VM from an image) but I don't see how this could be the cause as the cron is running.

Any suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: Please try to disable cron jobs. That will be not the case. It works fine. Flat Catalog Enabled?

Comment: I have flat catalog disabled